# wait for button click on button click move button to a slot in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I get the title wasn't the best but I don't quite know how to explain it. I tkinter I want to make square widgets with "slots on them. When the app is run I want buttons to show up at the top of the screen and a 4x4 grid of the square widgets. the app to wait for a user to click on a button. Then that button should move into the top left slot on the top left square. After this is done the user should repeat the process and the next button should go into the next slot on the top left square and so on until the square is full, the repeat the process with the next square. The should also be an fixed position button that allows me to pass on a slot without putting things in it? How should I accomplish this? I already have the for loop I need:

```
 for elem in zip(*l):
    for a in elem:
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your problem correctly, but it looks like at the core, you're basically trying to reposition tkinter widgets, correct?

You can do this with your geometry manager. If you use the `grid` method (which in your case I would recommend) then you can do:

```
def changeButtonPostion():
    button2.grid_remove() #gets rid of the widget in the top left corner
    button.grid(row=0, column=1) #the top left corner of your 4x4 grid
```

Otherwise, you can use the `pack_forget` method if you use the `pack` geometry manager.

Comment: You don't need the call to `grid_remove` in this case. Merely putting it somewhere else guarantees it will vanish from where it was.